# Can not change SELinux security context on Gluster FS folder

Tags: selinux, glusterfs, fuse

I can not change the security context of a folder which is created inside a Gluster-FS volume. Following is the error I keep getting.

`chcon: failed to change context of ‘test’ to ‘system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0’: Operation not supported`

I would be really grateful if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to set SELinux contexts on files in GlusterFS volumes was added in [GlusterFS 3.11.0](https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release-notes/3.11.0/). AFAIK Red Hat has not yet shipped this version or a later version of GlusterFS in RHEL or [Red Hat Gluster Storage](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2356261). However, it is available in Fedora, and [in CentOS 7](https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/Storage/Gluster) by installing `centos-release-gluster312` or `centos-release-gluster313` depending on the desired version.

Comment: Upgraded Gluster to 3.13 version and still getting the same error. So I have disabled Selinux temporarily.